# DVD or Bluray editing tool

Tags: video

I would like to ask if anybody can propose a tool that can create a DVD or a BluRay from a set of Movies, files etc.. The most important functionality for the tool should be that it could add a button to the menu that can open a url outside of the actual disk.

The main purpose is to find a list of softwares that can create a DVD/Bluray with a  menu which one can start a set of videos(mp4, wav, mpeg and maybe m4v formats) in a sequence and also be able to go to a webpage by clicking on a button.

The software should run on windows 64bit. In regards to styling and menu generation, the least complicated the better. The software will be used mostly be researchers in the field of astronomy, so I think the software should be able to auto generate the menus and do the styling itself. Of course, the software should also allow the user to do a bit of styling such as changing the background picture, the font, and button types.

In regards to the budget, I would like to create a list of software that I can present with different prices so that the manger can select the one they want.

The license is of no issue since it will only be used as a standalone software.

Comment: We'll need much more information to provide a solid recommendation. Please see http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/46 and [edit] your question to conform to the guidelines there - what operating system should it run on? What is your budget?

Comment: Also: What (file) types are the (input) movies using that must be supported? Should the menus be auto-generated, or do you (additionally) want to style them yourself? In the latter case, what must be supported for styling (pictures, text coloring, transitions, movie-clips as "preview picture", …)? Any license implications (e.g. commercial use/sell of resulting disks)?